# Telegram bot node js повторяет многократно одинаковое сообщение

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Написал простого бота на node js. Данный бот просто задает одни и теже вопросы, на которые надо отвечать из предложеных вариантов ответа. При первом запуске все нормально, но если начать цикл заново, то уже на втором вопросе он задает его дважды. Потом трижды и так далее. Я не понимаю почему так происходит.

Модуль для node js иcпользовал этот node-telegram-bot-api [Ссылка](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)

Сам код:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = "ВВЕДИТЕ_ВАШ_ТОКЕН";
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

var l1 = "left";
var r1 = "right";

var g1 = "Good";
var b1 = "Bad";

  bot.onText(/\/step2/, (msg) => {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Who is playing?\n And you must write <<И>>", {});
        bot.on('text', (msg) => {
        if (msg.text.toLowerCase().includes("и")) {
          bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "This is left or right?", {
            "reply_markup": {
              "keyboard": [[l1 , r1]]
            }
          });
          bot.on('text', (msg) => {
            if (msg.text === l1) {
              bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Good or bad?", {
                "reply_markup": {
                  "keyboard": [[g1 , b1]]
                }
              });
              bot.on('text', (msg) => {
                if (msg.text === g1) {
                  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "So, you can go \n /step3", {});
                } else if (msg.text === b1) {
                  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "So, you can go \n /step3", {});
                }
              });
            } else if (msg.text === r1) {
              bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Good or bad?", {
                "reply_markup": {
                  "keyboard": [[g1 , b1]]
                }
              });
              bot.on('text', (msg) => {
                if (msg.text === g1) {
                  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "So, you can go \n /step3", {});
                } else if (msg.text === b1) {
                  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "So, you can go \n /step3", {});
                }
              });
            }
          });
          } else {}
      });
    });
```

Что тут не так? Почему первый вопрос не повторяет? Как решить эту проблему, кроме бесконечного перезапуска программы?

Comment: отладку не пробовали использовать, чтоб понять как ветвятся проходы и с какими значениями?

Comment: Пробывал, поэтому и спрашиваю тут из за того, что не к чему не пришел. А что значит с какими значениями?